# not able to show all the cells in toggle

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flip").click(function(){
    $("#panel").toggle(1000);
  });
});
```

link to jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/T8t2r/301/

Comment: ID's should be unique. Change flip to a class. Also, `#="mytable" {}` isn't a valid CSS selector.

Comment: ID's are unique, you need to use different ID's for all your elements, and you need to post better questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `id` must be unique on your DOM and you have several elements with the same id. This is not valid and will cause the effect you're seeing: only toggle the first one.

Use css classes instead

**HTML**

```
<tr class="parent">
    <td><div class="flip">Cash and Equivalents</div></td>
    <td><div class="flip">000,000</div></td>
    <td><div class="flip">000,000</div></td>
    <td><div class="flip">000,000</div></td>

</tr>
<tr class="child">
    <td><div class="panel">Cash and Equivalents</div></td>
    <td><div class="panel">asdasdasd000,000</div></td>
    <td><div class="panel">000,000</div></td>
    <td><div class="panel">000,000</div></td>
</tr>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".flip").click(function(){
    $(".panel").toggle(1000);
  });
});
```

It seems to me that this could be much more simple though, but I'll need to know what you're trying to do exaclty

Comment: can I give each <tr> tag a separate id and do it ? coz div tag causing unnecessary divisions

Comment: actually I am iterating in the ruby code, to generate table elements, so how can I iterate through the jquery, I am new to jquery

Comment: @Hrishikesh Sardar: maybe you could explain better your requirement on your question, I'm sure we can come up with something simpler

Comment: Please see this I made a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17452760/collapsible-row-in-dynamic-table

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `class` attribute instead of an `id`. The `id` attribute is meant to be a single, unique selector, and is not meant to be used more than once. I have changed your code and updated your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/T8t2r/302/ to make it work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Id must be unique  on the DOM.

Inorder to get the required functionality,Change flip as  `class` in html and use `class` selector.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".flip").click(function(){
    $(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/T8t2r/307/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NgTQL/

corrected HTML `panel` and `flip` changed to a class:

```
<table id="mytable" border='1'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Revenue</th>
            <th>Expense</th>
            <th>Profit</th>
        </tr>
    <tbody>

    <tr class="parent">
        <td><div class="flip">Cash and Equivalents</div></td>
        <td><div class="flip">000,000</div></td>
        <td><div class="flip">000,000</div></td>
        <td><div class="flip">000,000</div></td>

            </tr>

    <tr class="child">
        <td><div class="panel">Cash and Equivalents</div></td>
        <td><div class="panel">asdasdasd000,000</div></td>
        <td><div class="panel">000,000</div></td>
        <td><div class="panel">000,000</div></td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".flip").click(function(){
    $(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```